# Start Editing a cell in JTable automaically

Tags: java, swing, jtable

> I am developing a restaurant billing system.
>
> So here is the order panel interface

[image]

So now when i click on the menuTable the item code automatically gets added to kotTable

and when i press "Q" the focus shifts to quantity column in kotTable.

[image]`

```
private void menuTableKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)      


{

                               
    
     if(evt.getKeyChar()=='Q') {
        
         kotTable.editCellAt(i-1,2);
        
                      
         
     }
}  `
```

The problem is **The cell doesnt start editing automatically. I need to click on   that cell and then the editing starts.**
i tried using DefaultCellEditor , getInputMap() and many other. But I am bit confused and the problem is not solved.. Thanx

Comment: Try focusing the cell first, then enable editing.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [key binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), you can map the <kbd>Q</kbd> key to the table's `"startEditing"` action. More examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:230513%20%5Bjtable%5D%20startediting).

```
table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, 0), "startEditing");
```